# How to get signature for Amazon S3 HTTP request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm following this example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html where a GET request can be seen like this:

```
GET / [destinationObject] HTTP/1.1
Host: [BucketName].s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-request-payer : requester
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2009 12:00:00 GMT
Authorization: AWS [Signature]
```

Moreover, if we follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationConstructingCanonicalizedAmzHeaders where we can see a GET request like this:

```
GET /photos/puppy.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000

Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:
bWq2s1WEIj+Ydj0vQ697zp+IXMU=
```

If `AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE`is AWSAccessKeyId then how `bWq2s1WEIj+Ydj0vQ697zp+IXMU=` is generated?

Comment: The second part of the (mis-named) Authorization header is a signature. You can see how it's constructed at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader. You can simplify life by using an AWS SDK to do this work for you.

Comment: @jarmod for some reason I have to restrict myself using HTTP request, otherwise I love aws-cli and using an `s3` URL is very simple.